# Check touch outside button not working in recycleview (setOnTouchListener)

Tags: android

I am not able to detect that touch move outside the button by check x,y inside rectangle,

```
{
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
      if(!outRect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
                        // User moved outside bounds
      }
   }
}
return false;
```

but the view is a child of recycleview, it's not worked

Comment: I would not detect the touch outside with coordinates, put the button inside a container and detect the click on the container to understand when the user clicks in the area that contains the button

Answer (score 0):

what feature exactly you want. is it that you want do something when click out side button and when user clicks the button do something else then

try this :

setOnTouchListner to the whole layout

```
    Layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           // do somethin here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and as well as to button button:

```
     addFile.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   // do somethin here
 }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and add this to the layout of your button:

```
  android:clickable="true"
```

Try this and it might work